# Jenkins + Kubernetes + Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-helm

I am new to kubernetes, how can I make full CI/CD pipeline to create dockers images from jenkins and deploying it to kubernetes cluster running minikube.

I need three containers:
1. frontend: react
2. backend: nodejs
3. mongodb
and nginx webserver. 
I have Jenkins master, Docker and Minikube installed. 
[My App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjW8w.png)

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: frontend
    build: ./client
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    links:
    - node
    volumes:
    - ./client/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html"
  node:
    container_name: server
    build: ./server
    env_file:
    - ./server/.env.example
    ports:
    - "3001:3001"
    links:
    - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
```

Comment: Have a look at Jenkins X (https://jenkins-x.io/). Sounds like it could serve all your needs.

Comment: So I have done this, but it was a large project with a sizeable amount of code. That strongly implies this question is too broad, which is what current close votes are for. Please break this question up into several smaller questions.

Comment: I need urgently help..

Answer (score 0):

Matt mentioned that this question is too broad and I agree. You did not provide required details and what exactly do you want to achieve.

You can use Jenkins, Docker, Ansible, Helm and Kubernetes stack and it has been explained in this medium [article](https://medium.com/containerum/configuring-ci-cd-on-kubernetes-with-jenkins-89eab7234270).

For ease of use you can also use [Kubernetes Continuous Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Continuous+Deploy+Plugin)
In this case you will need to configure a Job and select "Deploy to Kubernetes" and add the kubeconfig (explained in the provided link).

Last but not least just as @t3ng1l mentioned [Jenkins X](https://jenkins-x.io/getting-started/install-on-cluster/)  was created for such purposes.

Comment: Thank you @aurelius. I understand. Can you please provide me your e-mail adress ? I want to ask you something private about this field.